# How does the "emergency access" feature of LastPass work?

Tags: encryption, password-management, decryption, lastpass

How does the "emergency access" feature of LastPass work? I can't find detailed information about the used cryptographic methods.

How can I be sure that LastPass is not keeping a copy of my master-password to decrypt the files in case of an emergency access request?

Comment: Did you try to search for it on Google first? https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/emergency-access/

Answer (score 5):

While the strict answer to the question can be found in the [LastPass Help Centre](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=11538), what is interesting on the info they provide is that by enabling it you make your account as secure as the master password of the relying party (on a threath model where the attacker has access to encrypted data like lastpass has).

If you have a strong one, but the other person uses a weak one, the attacker (or lastpass) could get into your passwords.

Comment: Exactly that. And why the Emergency Access contact can't use his private key without authorization from lastpass and decrypt the key, and so the files, sooner that allowed?

Comment: The trusted contact does not have access to the encrypted key before they provide it. The security is that they wont provide it and probably put a good effort on avoiding anyone has access to it before the date too. That is, of course, a potential security problem.